# Where clause wtih double OR operator in laravel 8 controller

Tags: laravel

I need to lookin' for data that the where clause have 3 condition, so its need OR operator twice, here is the code in my controller, I use laravel 8

```
$salesTransactions = SalesTransaction::when($request->keyword, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query
        ->where('tanggal_transaksi', 'like', "%{$request->keyword}%")
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$request->keyword}%")
        ->orWhere('status', 'like', "%{$request->keyword}%");
    })->join('distributors', 'distributors.id', '=', 'sales_transactions.distributor_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'distributors.user_id')
    ->select('sales_transactions.*', 'users.name')
    ->orderBy('tanggal_transaksi', 'DESC')->latest('sales_transactions.id')->paginate(25);
```

I got the error, but dont know how to solve, the problem is I cant use OR operator twice, any idea ? Thanks

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Comment: Why can't you use "OR" twice? You can use it as many times you like

Comment: what is error you are getting. Query error or Unexpected results after search ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to group an "or" condition within parentheses, you may pass a closure as the first argument to the orWhere method. Like:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('votes', '>', 100)
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'Abigail')
                      ->where('votes', '>', 50);
            })
            ->get();
```